# Make input field display form text

Tags: laravel

I want users to be able to read and edit their 'About me' text. So far, all works fine, the updated text populates correctly on their profile page. Awesome.

However, I can't get the text to remain in the textform field, which is annoying.

Here's an example of when it **does** work:

I enable users to update their 'Name' and the name remains viewable in the form.

```
label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>
```

Now, I know that `textareas` work differently, and I also have a working example where I enable users to update their 'Group Description' and, again, the textarea remains viewable in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="group_description">Group Description:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="group_description">{{ $group->group_description }}</textarea>
</div>
```

However, I can't get the '**About me**' text to display the textarea?

Here's what I have:

```
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="about_me">{{ $user->about_me) }}</textarea>
        @error('about_me')
```

I get an error on submission: `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' (View:  -->`

The good news is, I can use the below code which does update the '**About me**' text, but it will not show the text in the textarea as I need:

```
<textarea class="form-control @error('about_me') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $user->about_me }}" id="about_me" type="text" rows="5" name="about_me" autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: Remove the ) at ```{{ $user->about_me) }}```

Comment: [<textarea> doesn't have value and type attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). you need just  `<textarea class="form-control @error('about_me') is-invalid @enderror"  id="about_me" rows="5" name="about_me" autofocus>{{ $user->about_me }}</textarea>`

Comment: Thanks guys, this sorted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a wrong format to initialize textarea to display text on it! Here's the code!

```
<textarea class="form-control @error('about_me') is-invalid @enderror" id="about_me" rows="5" name="about_me" autofocus>{{ $user->about_me }}</textarea>
```